# How to subset a graph based on community membership and size in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to subset a graph based on the community membership in the condition that I don't want the communities of size 1 included in the result in (graph of size 1)
what I came up with but not a successful one :

```
karate <- graph.famous("Zachary")
karate <- add.vertices(karate, 6) #to have zero degree vertices
wckarate=walktrap.community(karate) 
lapply(sort(unique(membership(wckarate))), function(g) {
  subg<-induced.subgraph(karate, which((membership(wckarate)==g)  & ( sizes( wckarate)[[g]]!=1)))})
```

result :

```
[[1]]
IGRAPH U--- 9 15 -- Zachary
+ attr: name (g/c)

[[2]]
IGRAPH U--- 7 6 -- Zachary
+ attr: name (g/c)

[[3]]
IGRAPH U--- 9 15 -- Zachary
+ attr: name (g/c)

[[4]]
IGRAPH U--- 4 4 -- Zachary
+ attr: name (g/c)

[[5]]
IGRAPH U--- 5 6 -- Zachary
+ attr: name (g/c)

[[6]]
IGRAPH U--- 0 0 -- Zachary
+ attr: name (g/c)

....

[[11]]
IGRAPH U--- 0 0 -- Zachary
+ attr: name (g/c)
```

How to avoid to have NULL graph object?

thank you in advance

Comment: writing it here speed my brain processing procedure 100times :)... I find my answer I should first delete these vertices before sub-setting the graph